# How to visualize a borehole profile (stacked bar plot) with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I want to plot several drilling spots where each of them shows geological borehole data along a z-axis. As a final result it should look like this example here:

[image: Example of how it could look like]

**My data looks like this:**

```
X layer.thickness layer.depth ID Category BSCategory
0             0.2         0.2  1     silt  Drilling1
0             1.0         1.2  2   gravel  Drilling1
0             3.0         3.2  3     silt  Drilling1
0             0.4         0.4  4     silt  Drilling2
0             0.8         1.2  5   gravel  Drilling2
0             2.0         3.2  6     sand  Drilling2
```

**So far I have two approaches (see code below):**

**1.Try:**

It doesn't start at 0 and my colors/categories are rotated by 1 step.

**2.Try:**

- Mixes up layer ordering
- groups values together (it schould be silt, then gravel, then silt again in the Drilling1 example).

I know this is by intention of the `geom_bar()` method, but can I deactivate the grouping and sorting?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(X = 0, layer.thickness = c(0.2,1,3,0.4,0.8,2),layer.depth = c(0.2,1.2,3.2,0.4,1.2,3.2), ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),Category=c("silt","gravel","silt","silt","gravel","sand"),BSCategory=c("Drilling1","Drilling1","Drilling1","Drilling2","Drilling2","Drilling2"))

# 1. Try:
q <- qplot(x=X, y = layer.thickness,data = df, color = Category, group=1, geom="line",lwd=1)
q + facet_grid(. ~ BSCategory)
# Problem: Does not start at 0. Categories / Colors are rotated by 1 step.

# 2. Try:
# Best try so far
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = BSCategory, y = layer.thickness, fill = Category, color=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
# Problem: Mixes up layer ordering
# groups values together (it schould be silt gravel silt in the Drilling1 example)


# Maybe good alternatives?
geom_linerange()
geom_vline()
geom_segment()
```

Output of the 1.Try:

[image: output of the 1.Try]

Output of the 2.Try:

[image: Output of the 2. Try]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may `group` by "ID" and `reverse` the default stacking order. You may also reverse the y-axis (`scale_y_reverse`) to reflect depth.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = BSCategory, y = layer.thickness, group = ID, fill = Category)) +
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
    scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: @Valentin Please note the edit. I just remembered that there is an `position_stack(reverse = TRUE)` argument. No need for the 'reversed' id variable.

Comment: Thanks @Hendrik! Your solutions works fine until I reach 10 individual items in each column. After that it orders my layers like this: 1,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. How can I solve that? You can find an example image here with the plotted `ix` as labels:  [1] (https://imgur.com/a/qGBVO)

Comment: @Valentin It seems like your "ID" column is a `factor`. Make sure it is `numeric`. E.g. this works fine: `d <- data.frame(BS = "d1", ID = 1:12, thick = sample(1:4, 12, replace = TRUE), cat = sample(c("silt", "gravel", "sand"), 12, replace = TRUE))`; `ggplot(d, aes(x = BS, y = thick, group = ID, fill = cat)) + geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE), color = "black") + scale_y_reverse()` (just added `color` to distinguish between consecutive layers of same 'cat' in this toy example)